# ASP.NET aspx page code runs impersonated though impersonation is disabled

Tags: asp.net, authentication, impersonation

I have a blank test app created in VS 2005 as ASP.NET application. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx) that

> By default, ASP.NET does not use impersonation, and your code runs using the ASP.NET application's process identity.

And I have the following web.config

```
<configuration>

    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>

    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" />
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <identity impersonate="false"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So it seem impersonation is disabled just like [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx) is suggesting.

My aspx is blank default and the codebehind is

```
namespace TestWebapp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Before1: Current Princupal = {0}", Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name));
            WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero);
            try
            {
                int a = 0;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("After: Current Princupal = {0}", Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name));
            } finally
            {
                ctx.Undo();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I reload the page I get the following debug output:

> [5288] Before1: Current Princupal =
>   DOMAIN\User
>   [5288] After: Current Princupal =
>   DOMAIN\User

Output is the same with

```
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

The web site uses Default Application Pool and the pool is set up to use NETWORK SERVICE account for its worker processes.
I'm sure the application uses the web.config it should use and the w3p.exe worker process is running under NETWORK SERVICE.

What can be wrong in this case?

Thanks!

@Edit: Rob, thanks for the tip! 
The $user shortcut shows me that everything is happening as I expect: with impersonation on I have the process running user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    and the thread has DOMAIN\User before WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero) and "No Token. Thread not impersonating." after.
But Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name still give me DOMAIN\User in both places.

@Edit: I've found out that to get Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.Current.User changed I have to manually do it:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

I'm not sure what's the point here, but anyway. I now have a problem with sharepoint shared services manage user profile permission but that's another question.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your problem here.

Things to know before moving further,

1. There are different security context while an application is running. Like `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, and the one you mentioned above, i.e. `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`
2. In a web application, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` is always provided by `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`.

Coming to your point. If you want to modify `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`, then modify `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` which initially provided by your authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Seems odd, A few things to try:

- While in on a breakpoint in Debug type $user in a watch window, that will show you the process and thread identities.
- Your use of impersonate is incorrect, try this code:

  ```
  // Declare the logon types as constants
  const long LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
  const long LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;

  // Declare the logon providers as constants
  const long LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
  const long LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;
  const long LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2;
  const long LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1;

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "LogonUser")]
  private static extern bool LogonUser(
      string lpszUsername,
      string lpszDomain,
      string lpszPassword,
      int dwLogonType,
      int dwLogonProvider,
      ref IntPtr phToken);

  public static WindowsImpersonationContext ImpersonateCurrentUserBegin(System.Net.NetworkCredential credential)
  {
      WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
      if (credential == null || credential.UserName.Length == 0 || credential.Password.Length == 0 || credential.Domain.Length == 0)
      {
          throw new Exception("Incomplete user credentials specified");
      }
      impersonationContext = Security.Impersonate(credential);
      if (impersonationContext == null)
      {
          return null;
      }
      else
      {
          return impersonationContext;
      }
  }

  public static void ImpersonateCurrentUserEnd(WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext)
  {
      if (impersonationContext != null)
      {
          impersonationContext.Undo();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this tip about $user. For $user it shows that (I have <identity impersonate="true"> now) everything is as I would expect. There is a token of the impersonated user before WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero) and no token after, and the process is under NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: But System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name still give me the impersonated user.

Answer (score 1):

What does  `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` give you?

Assume you've checked the security tab within IIS that it allows anonymous access?

Are you within an active directory that has some strange local policy?

Comment: The same result with HttpContext.User.Identity.Name as with Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, and it is also the same with anonymous access allowed or not.

Comment: I don't know about domain policies, gotta try to do it in another domain.